# How to make progress bar of activity visible in fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-progressbar

I defined a fragement and it was loaded in an activity, there is a progress bar in the activity layout, how can I make the progress bar visible when in the fragment

Comment: Since a fragment can have its own xml layout just like an activity. You can define the progress bar within that layout. Read more on fragments [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Answer (score 0):

> How to make progress bar of activity visible in fragment

Use `getActivity().findViewById` in Fragment for accessing views from parent Activity of Fragments:

```
Progressbar progressBar = (ProgressBar) 
                getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress_bar_id);
```

Now use `progressBar` to show and hide `Progressbar`.

**Note:** Make sure adding Fragments in FragmentManager  after calling `setContentView` in Activity